# How is it OK to safely neglect one-step difference of the system state in this paper?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I’m reading [a very informative paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8794351?casa_token=ae6n4UMp3PMAAAAA:6CMvOBfrGuthgxyppnXDcqn-pRGp7yP2FnT7jw9ItbfSfvkb_Yy6qjunmnZr1VNXhme_0b7QGA). But I met some formulations hard to understand.

In assumption 2, they have the inequality of one step difference,

$$\Delta u_k \leq \sigma(B_o^{-1})\big(L_a\Delta u_{k-1}+L_a\Delta \zeta_k + m\Delta \dot{v}_{r,k}+\lambda_{\max}(K_v)\Delta s_k+\Delta\tau_{d,k}\big)$$

where $\Delta (\cdot)_k=\|(\cdot)_k-(\cdot)_{k-1}\|$ denotes one step difference; and $\zeta$, $\dot{v}$,  $s$ are variables for the drone position, and $\tau$ for the attitude respectively.

The state they can safely neglect $\Delta\zeta$, $\Delta\dot{v}$,  $\Delta s$ since the rate of the attitude control is much higher than that of the position control.

This part is hard to understand. What they focus is whether the drone positioning can safely be done using a machine learning and thus this ignoring seems to assume that the positioning system is already stable (a circle reasoning).

Or do I take the context wrong? Please help me understand how it is OK to safely neglect one-step difference of the position variables.

*FYI, I asked them this question directly 2 month ago (plus the reminder 2 weeks ago) and I do not have the reply yet.

Comment: To me this looks like a confusing abuse of notation, since they also state that the three controllers (attitude, speed, position) run at different update rates ($>100$ Hz, $> 5$ Hz, $\approx 10$ Hz). The upper bound for the one-step difference of the control law seems to contain all these terms, so it isn't even clear to me what "one-step difference" in this context is supposed to mean; one step of the slowest update rate? Or the fastest? Or a mixture? Unfortunatly, I couldn't find any details on this point, so it is hard to say what they actually mean. Did you try ask the authors directly?

Comment: @SampleTime Thank you sir. According to the context, I bet they mean one-step difference of the next one in the rate to the position (100Hz) but I'm not sure. If it becomes clear, the ignoring is still hard  to accept since ignoring the terms of position seems to assume the system is already stable. Yes, I did try twice (2 month, 2 weeks ago), toward the first and second author and do not have the reply yet :(